# Targeting the last child in 8 column grid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

DOM:

```
<div class="someGroup">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="col-md-3 item"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3 item"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3 item"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3 item"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="col-md-3 item"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3 item"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3 item"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3 item"></div> <!-- I want to target this div -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to do with CSS?

I tried using `.someGroup .item:last-child`, but it also targets the last child of the first `col-md-6`.

Basically, I need to have 8 equal columns and this was the best approach I could come up with. If any other suggestions, I'm all ears! :)

Comment: `.someGroup > div:last-child > div:last-child` best regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You also need to ensure you're only selecting the last `col-md-6` element.

```
.someGroup .col-md-6:last-child .item:last-child {}
```

***Demo:*** http://jsfiddle.net/w83qwtx0/

Comment: Right, of course.. Silly mistake, thanks! :) I will accept the answer as soon as available.

Answer (score 0):

If you also add a selector for the last child that's 'col-md-6', then it will only target the one you want. So, your selector would be:
'.someGroup .col-md-6:last-child .item:last-child'